# Rails trouble with Rspec and Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to get around with Rails. It's my first Rails app and I am testing it in a process of evaluation for our future projects. I've followed railstutorial.org all the way up to chapter 9 and then tried to go on my own.

Using Rails 3.2.3,Ruby 1.9.3, Factory Girl 1.4.0 and rspec 2.10.0.

The trouble I'm getting is with a Client--[has_many]-->User relationship.

The error I can't get through when running tests:

```
1) User 
     Failure/Error: let(:client) { FactoryGirl.create(:client) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `user' for #<Client:0x000000045cbfa8>
```

spec/factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :client do
    sequence(:company_name)  { |n| "Company #{n}" }
    sequence(:address) { |n| "#{n} Example Street"}   
    phone "0-123-456-7890"
  end

  factory :user do
    sequence(:name)  { |n| "Person #{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"}   
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"
    client

    factory :admin do
      admin true
    end
  end
```

spec/models/user_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  let(:client) { FactoryGirl.create(:client) }
  before { @user = client.users.build(name: "Example User", 
                        email: "user@example.com", 
                        password: "foobar", 
                        password_confirmation: "foobar") }

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
end
```

app/controllers/clients_controller.rb

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @client = Client.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @client = Client.new
    @client.users.build # Initializes an empty user to be used on new form
  end

  def create
    @client = Client.new(params[:client])
    if @client.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
      redirect_to @client
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  .
  .
  .

  def new
     @user = User.new
  end

  .
  .
  .
end
```

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client

  .
  .
  .
end
```

app/models/client.rb

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
  .
  .
  .

end
```

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your user_spec you're calling `client.users`, but it appears elsewhere that client belongs to user (singular). If so, try something like:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :client do
    ...
    association :user
  end
end

describe User do
   let(:user) { FactoryGirl( ... ) }
   let(:client) { FactoryGirl(:client, :user => user) }
   subject { user }
   it { should respond_to(:name) }
end
```

Comment: Actually, user should belong to client and client has many users. I will update the question with my models. Maybe I somehow messed up the associations there...

Comment: Thanks @Mori. I've updated with my models. I'm not sure whether or not your solution still applies. I really want the relationship to be client--[has_many]-->user and, therefore, user--[belongs_to]-->client

Comment: Turned out there was a forgotten line in the model that indeed redefined the :user attribute in Client. Thanks.